# The different between Browser native css display: grid and bootstrap grid system?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I just read the [Chrome 57 release log](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/nic57) and noticed start from version 57, Chrome native support css style - [display: grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids), it seems late to come because bootstrap having grid system since version 2 and on the [early of 2014](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/03/Get-on-the-CSS-Grid), Chrome team already aware the grid system and can be enable by flags panel.

I have read the article above but it doesn't turn out the PROS over some css framework like bootstrap/foundation etc.

So I curious is it any advantage using native grid css?

Answer (score 0):

[**CSS Grid Layout**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/) is currently the most powerful layout system that CSS can offer, the drawback is its [**current browser support**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid).

Your question is kind of opinion-based so I will try to mark some real problems I have faced when using frameworks.

Some problems you may face when using a framework:

- You will probably end up with [technical debt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt).
- Frameworks generally have a lot of CSS rules you are not actually going to use, making your CSS file heavier than what it needs to be.
- Some of the CSS rules that you **will** use may have over-specific selectors that require higher complexity than needed to override properties.
- Some frameworks have unsemantic HTML code, which will cause unexpected behavior if changed.

---

Many experienced front-end web developers avoid using frameworks because they tend to slow down instead of helping getting things done faster, specially when working on complex projects.

Many articles will discourage using frameworks, many others will encourage it.
Personally I think **it depends on the requirements of the project you are working on.**